# SQL where restrictions

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Below is my output, I want to display only those names that repeat. Each name is a pilot and the number is the type of airplane the pilot fly's. I want to display the names of pilots who fly more than one airplane. I am using sql*plus

```
PIL_PILOTNAME                  DEP_EQUIP_NO 
------------------------------ ------------ 
Gladchuk, Chet                 1085
Gladchuk, Chet                 1345
Green, Edward L.               1489
Harris, Kenneth C.             1253
Leiss, Ernst L.                1194
Long, Stuart                   1081
Pasewark, William B.           1026
Pasewark, William B.           1347
Scamell, Richard               1368
```

My output should only display:

```
PIL_PILOTNAME                  DEP_EQUIP_NO 
------------------------------ ------------ 
Gladchuk, Chet                 1085
Gladchuk, Chet                 1345
Pasewark, William B.           1026
Pasewark, William B.           1347
```

Here's my query:

```
select distinct pil_pilotname,dep_equip_no from pilots  join departures
on dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id  join equip_type
on eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no
order by pil_pilotname;
```

Comment: I attempted to answer your question about displaying maximum pay for pilots (8451995) but it appears to be deleted now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the best option would be to use analytics

```
select PIL_PILOTNAME, DEP_EQUIP_NO
from (
        select pil_pilotname,dep_equip_no, count(*) over (partition by pil_pilot_id) as cnt
        from pilots
            join departures on (dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id)
            join equip_type on (eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no)
    )
where cnt > 1
order by pil_pilotname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select distinct pil_pilotname,dep_equip_no, COUNT(*) AS FlightCount from pilots  join departures
on dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id  join equip_type
on eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no
group by pil_pilotname
having FlightCount > 1;
```

- http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/group-by-having-sum-avg-and-count.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Note that you'll also need to check the count of duplicates - finding some documentation for you.

Comment: can't select pil_pilotname, dep_equipno when grouping only on pil_pilotname

Comment: I didn't see Oracle at the time I posted the answer - good point.

Answer (score 0):

One of these two (or both) should work

```
select distinct pil_pilotname, dep_equip_no, count(*) as c from pilots
join departures on dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id  
join equip_type on eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no
group by pil_pilotname
where c > 1
order by pil_pilotname;
```

Or

```
select distinct p1.pil_pilotname, p1.dep_equip_no from pilots p1
join departures d1 on d1.dep_pilot_id = p1.pil_pilot_id  
join equip_type e1 on e1.eq_equip_no = d1.dep_equip_no
where exists (
    select distinct p2.pil_pilotname from pilots p2
    join departures d2 on d2.dep_pilot_id = p2.pil_pilot_id  
    join equip_type e2 on e2.eq_equip_no = d2.dep_equip_no
    where p1.dep_equip_no != p2.dep_equip_no
)
order by p1.pil_pilotname;
```

Comment: can't select pil_pilotname, dep_equipno when grouping only on pil_pilotname

Answer (score 0):

```
select  pil_pilotname,dep_equip_no from pilots,departures,equip_type
where dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id  and eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no
group by pil_pilotname
having count(pil_pilotname) >1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not pulling anything from the `equip_type` table, in which case you might not need to join to it. I'm assuming here that `dep_equip_no` is a foreign key to `equip_type.eq_equip_no` and thus cannot hold values not found in `equip_type`.

With that in mind, my solution would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.pil_pilotname,
  d.dep_equip_no
FROM pilots p
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dep_pilot_id
    FROM departures
    GROUP BY dep_pilot_no
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dep_equip_no) > 1
  ) s ON p.pil_pilot_id = s.dep_pilot_id
  INNER JOIN departures d ON p.pil_pilot_id = d.dep_pilot_id
```

Basically, apart from removing the join to `equip_type`, I only added one join to a subselect that returns a list of `dep_pilot_id` values having more than one distinct associated `dep_equip_no`.

If you think you need the `equip_type` table in your query, you can put the removed join back, it should not affect the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select pil_pilotname, dep_equip_no
from pilots
inner join departures d on dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id
inner join equip_type on eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no
where pil_pilotname in (
  select pil_pilotname 
  from pilots
  inner join departures d on dep_pilot_id = pil_pilot_id
  inner join equip_type on eq_equip_no = dep_equip_no
  group by pil_pilotname
  having count(*) > 1)
order by pil_pilotname;
```

This will give you what you need.  The inner select in the where does the filtering.